# Google+ does not show any images in a badge

Tags: google, google-workspace, google-plus

I have created both a Google+ [profile](https://plus.google.com/u/0/104428351748591530426/posts) and [page](https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/105761789199990286533/105761789199990286533/posts).

I'm having some issues with the creation of a Google+ Badge. I want to use this badge on [my website](http://www.literaturen.org), where I have installed diffderent Google+ Widgets.

The funny thing is that all of them show other profiles with nice badges that contain the Google+ button, photos and the count of followers.

I don't have the same luck with my IDs: I can't get them to display any images.

I've tried the [Profile Config Tool](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/personal-config) and I can get it to work with other IDs (e.g., `idolbin.com: 117634089072667507999` or `joomshaper: 106333042920846200705`), but not with my own (`104428351748591530426`).

What do you think goes wrong here?

Comment: hi thx for editing - if you have any idea - iwolud be glad. greetings martin

Answer (score 1):

There are two different badges, one for personal profiles (https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/personal-config) and one for Pages (https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/config).  Make sure you use the correct one depending on which ID you're using and what you want to link it for.

Comment: many thanks for the hint. I will try to make sure to use the right one...

Comment: with this personal id i cannot create a standard-bag
see 104428351748591530426
on this https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/config

why does this not work!?

Comment: 104428351748591530426 is your personal profile. You should use https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/personal-config

Comment: hi Prisoner - many thanks i will try it out later the day. I come back and report all my findings -  greetings to you.

Comment: hello dear Prisoner - i have tried it. With the above mentioned id it looks very funny - the standard badge looks interesting - without images and photos but with the block for the different circles... this is pretty intersting - i have no glue why it is so... But at the weekend i will have a closer look at all the things. I look at the options and i try to create a new (experimental) profile. I come back and report all my findings - greetings

Comment: hello again - now with this page id  - see 
105761789199990286533 

it runs well  - no issues ..: 
https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/config

see also here http://www.literaturen.org and http://www.schulcenter.org 

- now the image appears - see the schulcenter-badge on the right side (the right column on both sites)

thanks alot for your help 

greetings